# How can I reference an external SQL file using Airflow's BigQuery operator?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm currently using Airflow with the BigQuery operator to trigger various SQL scripts. This works fine when the SQL is written directly in the Airflow DAG file. For example:

```
bigquery_transform = BigQueryOperator(
        task_id='bq-transform',
        bql='SELECT * FROM `example.table`',
        destination_dataset_table='example.destination'
    )
```

However, I'd like to store the SQL in a separate file saved to a storage bucket. For example:

```
bql='gs://example_bucket/sample_script.sql'
```

When calling this external file I recieve a "Template Not Found" error.

I've seen some examples load the SQL file into the Airflow DAG folder, however, I'd really like to access files saved to a separate storage bucket. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference any SQL files in your Google Cloud Storage Bucket. Here's a following example where I call the file Query_File.sql in the sql directory in my airflow dag bucket.

```
CONNECTION_ID = 'project_name'

with DAG('dag', schedule_interval='0 9 * * *', template_searchpath=['/home/airflow/gcs/dags/'], max_active_runs=15, catchup=True, default_args=default_args) as dag:

battery_data_quality = BigQueryOperator(
  task_id='task-id',
  sql='/SQL/Query_File.sql',
  destination_dataset_table='project-name.DataSetName.TableName${{ds_nodash}}',
  write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
  bigquery_conn_id=CONNECTION_ID,
  use_legacy_sql=False,
  dag=dag
)
```

Comment: This works when storing the SQL file within the Airflow bucket -- however, I'd like to store the SQL file in a completely different storage bucket unrelated to Airflow. Is that possible? I should note I'm using Airflow through Google Cloud Composer.

Also, I notice you use `sql=` in the operator whereas I'm using `bql=`. I receive an additional error in Airflow that `bql` is required. I wonder if that is related?

Comment: I don't think you can...Cloud Composer mounts the GCS bucket using a FUSE driver. The documentation states that "Cloud Composer stores the source code for your workflows (DAGs) and their dependencies in specific folders in Cloud Storage...Each environment has an associated Cloud Storage bucket. Cloud Composer schedules only the DAGs in the Cloud Storage bucket."
Maybe you can work around it by using a BashOperator to copy the relevant files over to the airflow environment bucket?

Comment: And with regards to your "bql vs sql" comment, "bql" is now depreciated syntax in newer airflow versions, it's unrelated.

Comment: I've been using your solution but am trying to populate the SQL file through a Jinja template variable. For example `sql=''{{dag_run.conf['sql_file']}}`. The variable contains a string of the file name, like "example.sql". However, when airflow processes the variable it automatically drops the file extension. If I hardcode the filename with extension it works perfectly fine. Any ideas why file extensions are being dropped when using jinja template value inside the operator?

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider using the [gcs_to_gcs operator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/gcs_to_gcs.py) to copy things from your desired bucket into one that is accessible by composer.

Answer (score 0):

download works differently in GoogleCloudStorageDownloadOperator for Airflow version 1.10.3 and 1.10.15.

```js
 def execute(self, context):

        self.object = context['dag_run'].conf['job_name'] + '.sql'
        logging.info('filemname in GoogleCloudStorageDownloadOperator: %s', self.object)
        self.filename = context['dag_run'].conf['job_name'] + '.sql'

        self.log.info('Executing download: %s, %s, %s', self.bucket,
                      self.object, self.filename)
        hook = GoogleCloudStorageHook(
            google_cloud_storage_conn_id=self.google_cloud_storage_conn_id,
            delegate_to=self.delegate_to
        )
        file_bytes = hook.download(bucket=self.bucket,
                                   object=self.object)
        if self.store_to_xcom_key:
            if sys.getsizeof(file_bytes) < 49344:
                context['ti'].xcom_push(key=self.store_to_xcom_key, value=file_bytes.decode('utf-8'))
            else:
                raise RuntimeError(
                    'The size of the downloaded file is too large to push to XCom!'

                )
```